# WP8 WindowsPhoneTestFramework

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When i run tests on wp7 this works fine, but when i change settings to WP8 i am getting Timeout from WCF Service, what could be causing this. I Know wp8 runs as a own device in network instead of using hostmachine network like wp7, this is taken care of in new version of framework. WP8 has connection to Automation service.

Here is the link to framework
https://github.com/nokia-entertainment/WindowsPhoneTestFramework

And copy-paste from error:

```
Given my app is clean installed and running
    Trace:->creating datastore          
    Trace:->getting platform            
    Trace:->1 platform(s) found             
    Trace:->platform 'Windows Phone 8' found            
    Trace:->looking for device 'Device'             
    Trace:->5 devices found             
    Trace:->connecting to device...             
    Trace:->device Connected...             
    Trace:->building host...            
    Trace:->opening host...             
    Trace:->host open           
    Trace:->ensuring application is stopped...          
    Trace:->stopping application...             
    Trace:->application stopped             
    Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send          
WCF command messages ->: Timeout
    Trace:->ensuring application is stopped...          
    Trace:->stopping application...             
    Trace:->application stopped             
    Trace:->uninstalling xap from device...             
    Trace:->xap uninstalled from  device            
    Trace:->installing xap to device...             
    Trace:->xap installed           
    Trace:->launching app...            
    Trace:->app launched            
    Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send          
WCF command messages ->: Timeout
    Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send          
WCF command messages ->: Timeout
    Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send
```

Same problem with Device and emulator.

Although app starts on device and emulator, but then timeout.

Comment: Ah, found solution :), was caused by host pc name and domain ending with .net. forced IP and port directly and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the firewall prevent your wcf service from connecting the wp8.
you can execute the following cmd with administrator privileges.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8085/ user=<domain>\<user>
```